# CSS Flexbox 3 columns Grid (4X4 + 1 large)

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to figure out how to get this in Flexbox, but the only thing I can get is in the code snippet:

[image]

Do you have an idea to manage this CSS only (I can't really touch the structure of the HTML as it is a PHP `foreach` loop)?

Could using CSS `grid` help here?

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.photo {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  align-self: flex-start;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}

.photo:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.large {
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="photo large"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Michael_B I couldn't find much help with the two questions you linked… My divs are responsive squares so it makes it more complex, all the examples are based on a fixed width column which is not my case

Comment: Something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/57rz2mgk/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on then fact that this is *squares*, you can simply position the *large* absolute, to the right, and the *smaller*, with their *padding-top* trick, will controls the *large's* height.

Then, by setting a padding on the `grid`, we keep the *smaller* on the left side and make space on the right for the *large*.

Additionally, we also need to change the *small* to be 50% of the space, not 25%.

Stack snippet

```css
.grid {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-right: 50%;
}

.photo {
  position: relative;
  flex: 0 0 calc(50% - 20px);
  margin: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}

.photo:not(.large):after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.large {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="photo large"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice one man! Didn't thought of that. It does the trick pretty well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `css grid`, just be mindful of its [compatibility](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-grid) with Internet Explorer.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
  grid-template: "item1 item2 large large" "item3 item4 large large" 
}

.photo {
  background: black;
}
.large {
  grid-area:large;
}
.photo:nth-of-type(2){ grid-area:item1;}
.photo:nth-of-type(3){ grid-area:item2;}
.photo:nth-of-type(4){ grid-area:item3;}
.photo:nth-of-type(5){ grid-area:item4;}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="photo large"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
  <div class="photo"></div>
</div>
```